# nextInt() splitting integers improperly

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file consisting of integers separated by spaces.  NextInt() seems to be splitting the last zero off of the integers.  So, 90 is read as 9 and 0.  500 is read as 50 and 0.

Has anyone seen this before?

```
FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("test.txt");

Scanner input = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(fs));

int u = 0;

while (u < 200) {
    test.i = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(test.i);
    u++;
}

fs.close();
```

This was just a loop to test if I was reading the file correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: What's the exact content of test.txt, and the complete output from running the program?

Comment: The file is formatted as follows, 0 9
0 50
0 268
0 1845
0 1940
0 2338
0 2548
0 3670
0 3674

Comment: @DesperateCoder So, it's working correctly then?

Comment: i'm new to this coding business.  is there a reason i don't see the spaces in the text file that you can think of?

Comment: So why do you think 90 is truncated to 9? because you have '9 0'?

Comment: @DesperateCoder it sounds like a weird problem with your editor. What editor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have floating number in the file which will through mismatch if you use nextInt() method. Secondly, your file may have space between 9 and 0 thats why they are printing 9 and 0 as two different integer.

Here is a sample code which does the same thing without any problem.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class IntReadFile {

    public static void main(String args[]){
    try{
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("text.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(fs));
        int u=0,i;
        while(u<30){
            i=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Integer read:"+i);
            u++;
        }
        sc.close();

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

This is a sample input of text.txt file and the code thus does fine.

- 1 2 3 3 3 4 5 90 20 20 20 10
- 10 10 3 3 4 5 90 20 20 20 10
- 3 3 4 5 90 20 20 20 10
- 3 3 4 5 90 20 20 20 10
- 3 3 4 5 90 20 20 20 10